# "object object" in Suggested review if reject option selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

This I found while reviewing suggested edit on stackoverflow... As you can see from screenshot below .. **[object Object]** is displayed and Im curious what that might be...

[image]

Steps to reproduce:-

- Visit [suggested edit review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3189877).
- When question pop up, click on reject option..

There it is...

Checked on Chrome(Version 30.0.1599.101 m) and FireFox(Version 25.0)

Comment: Reproduced on Mac OS X 10.8.5 with Chrome 30.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

A bit of JavaScript was expecting HTML and I was feeding it jQuery.

A rare case of too much jQuery.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: "A rare case of too much jQuery." :O